# How to detect running operating system?

Tags: ocaml

How can I detect system type / operating system in OCaml ?

My current idea is really weird. Running system call : `"uname -a"` with

```
let syscall ?(env=[| |]) cmd =
    let ic, oc, ec = Unix.open_process_full cmd env in
    let buf1 = Buffer.create 96
    and buf2 = Buffer.create 48 in
    (try
     while true do Buffer.add_channel buf1 ic 1 done
    with End_of_file -> ());
    (try
     while true do Buffer.add_channel buf2 ec 1 done
    with End_of_file -> ());
    let exit_status = Unix.close_process_full (ic, oc, ec) in
    check_exit_status exit_status;
    (Buffer.contents buf1,
    Buffer.contents buf2)
```

even on cygwin ...

But I guess there must be some native for ocaml way to check system type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard OCaml library has a string named `Sys.os_type`, but it doesn't contain as much information as `uname -a`.  It is either `"Unix"`, `"Win32"`, or `"Cygwin"`.  It's described in [the manual entry for the Sys module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Sys.html).

Answer (score 2):

NB there is also a [wrapper for uname](http://extunix.forge.ocamlcore.org/api/ExtUnixAll.html#VALuname) in extunix